# How to sync or migrate mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

How can i sync my old mongoose model with latest mongoose model ?

example if i have exist model called user with first name table and future i added more table like last_name. Table update, but just new user, old user is did't change.

old

```
new Schema {
first_name: String!
}
```

new table

```
new Schema{
first_name: String!
last_name: String!
}
```

Like laravel or django have feature built-in migration db. But how in mongodb or mongoose (express framework) ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package [`migrate-mongo`](https://github.com/seppevs/migrate-mongo).